# Implementation of recursive `ls` utility

Tags: c, file-system, linux

Recently I wrote my own implementation of a utility for recursive output of the directories' contents, kind of similar to the `ls` Linux utility with the `-Ro` flags. As a training, I wrote it in C.

I would love to hear your feedback on possible optimizations, better error handling, flaws in implementation, or the code in general.

I usually code in C++ and it so happened that I'm not very familiar with C, so <s>maybe</s> some places could have been implemented better, but I need someone experienced to point this out. Thanks!

```c
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024 /* initial size of the buffer for storing file information */
#define UNAME_MAX 32
#define DATE_LEN 20
#define PERM_LEN 10

#define MINOR_ERROR 1
#define FATAL_ERROR 2

enum file_type {
    REGULAR,
    DIRECTORY,
    SYMLINK,
    FIFO,
    SOCKET,
    EXECUTABLE,
    UNKNOWN
};

const char *file_type_str[] = { /* for some reason, this works faster than the array of chars. 
There may be some kind of alignment issues, not sure */
        [REGULAR]    = "",
        [DIRECTORY]  = "/",
        [SYMLINK]    = "@",
        [FIFO]       = "|",
        [SOCKET]     = "=",
        [EXECUTABLE] = "*",
        [UNKNOWN]    = "?"
};

struct file_info {
    struct stat st;
    enum file_type type;
    char *name;
    char *path;
    char *target;
};

struct user_info {
    char name[UNAME_MAX];
    uid_t uid;
    struct user_info *next;
};

static struct user_info *user_info_cache; /* cache the results of the expensive getpwuid() calls */

static int exit_status;

static void
init(void) {
    tzset(); /* call tzset() to initialize the timezone information before call to reentrant localtime_r()
    according to POSIX.1-2004 */
    setlocale(LC_COLLATE, ""); /* set the locale for collation aware string comparison */
}

static int
compare_file_name(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcoll(((const struct file_info *) a)->name, ((const struct file_info *) b)->name);
}

static void
*xmalloc(size_t size) {
    void *ptr = malloc(size);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        error(FATAL_ERROR, errno, "malloc");
        __builtin_unreachable(); /* if status given to error() is a nonzero value, error() calls exit(3)
        to terminate the program, so this line is unreachable */
    }
    return ptr;
}

static void
*xrealloc(void *ptr, size_t size) {
    void *new_ptr = realloc(ptr, size);
    if (new_ptr == NULL) {
        error(FATAL_ERROR, errno, "realloc");
        __builtin_unreachable();
    }
    return new_ptr;
}

static void
file_error(const char *message, const char *path) {
    error(0, errno, "%s: %s", message, path);
    exit_status = MINOR_ERROR;
}

static void
format_permissions(const mode_t mode, char *formatted) {
    formatted[0] = (mode & S_IRUSR) ? 'r' : '-';
    formatted[1] = (mode & S_IWUSR) ? 'w' : '-';
    formatted[2] = (mode & S_IXUSR) ? 'x' : '-';
    formatted[3] = (mode & S_IRGRP) ? 'r' : '-';
    formatted[4] = (mode & S_IWGRP) ? 'w' : '-';
    formatted[5] = (mode & S_IXGRP) ? 'x' : '-';
    formatted[6] = (mode & S_IROTH) ? 'r' : '-';
    formatted[7] = (mode & S_IWOTH) ? 'w' : '-';
    formatted[8] = (mode & S_IXOTH) ? 'x' : '-';
    formatted[9] = '\0';
}

static char
*get_owner(uid_t uid) {
    struct user_info *user_info;
    for (user_info = user_info_cache; user_info; user_info = user_info->next) {
        if (user_info->uid == uid) {
            return user_info->name;
        }
    }

    user_info = xmalloc(sizeof(struct user_info));

    const struct passwd *pwd = getpwuid(uid);
    if (pwd == NULL) {
        sprintf(user_info->name, "%u", uid); /* FIXME: known error:
        if given uid actually exists in the database and it's getpwuid() that just fails to retrieve it,
        we end up writing wrong username to cache */
    } else {
        strcpy(user_info->name, pwd->pw_name);
    }
    user_info->uid = uid;

    user_info->next = user_info_cache;
    user_info_cache = user_info;

    return user_info->name;
}

static void
format_time(const time_t mtime, char *formatted) {
    struct tm tm_info;
    localtime_r(&mtime, &tm_info); /* use reentrant version of localtime,
    as it's not required to call tzset() that causes overhead */
    strftime(formatted, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm_info);
}

static int
get_file_type(const mode_t st_mode) {
    switch (st_mode & S_IFMT) {
        case S_IFDIR:
            return DIRECTORY;
        case S_IFLNK:
            return SYMLINK;
        case S_IFIFO:
            return FIFO;
        case S_IFSOCK:
            return SOCKET;
        default:
            if (st_mode & S_IXUSR) { /* first check for executable bit,
            as regular files can be executable */
                return EXECUTABLE;
            } else if (S_ISREG(st_mode)) {
                return REGULAR;
            } else {
                return UNKNOWN;
            }
    }
}

static void
print_file_info(const struct file_info *file_info, const int owner_w, const int size_w) {
    char permissions[PERM_LEN];
    char date[DATE_LEN];
    char *owner;

    format_permissions(file_info->st.st_mode, permissions);
    format_time(file_info->st.st_mtime, date);
    owner = get_owner(file_info->st.st_uid);

    printf("%s %*s %*ld %s %s%s",
           permissions, owner_w,
           owner, size_w,
           file_info->st.st_size,
           date,
           file_type_str[file_info->type],
           file_info->name);
    if (file_info->target != NULL) {
        printf(" -> %s", file_info->target);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

static void
concat_path(const char *dir_name, const char *file_name, char *full_path) {
    char *end = stpcpy(full_path, dir_name);
    if (*(end - 1) != '/' && *file_name != '\0') {
        *end++ = '/';
    }
    strcpy(end, file_name);
}

static char
*read_link(const char *path, size_t expected_size) {
    if (expected_size == 0) { /* in some cases lstat() can report zero size for a pseudo-files that
        behave like symlinks, e.g. /proc/self/exe. We can't rely on this value, so instead fallback
        to _POSIX_SYMLINK_MAX as a guess to prevent multiple calls to readlink() and realloc() */
        expected_size = _POSIX_SYMLINK_MAX;
    }

    size_t buf_size = expected_size < PATH_MAX ? expected_size + 1 : PATH_MAX;
    char *buffer = xmalloc(buf_size);
    size_t read;

    while ((read = readlink(path, buffer, buf_size)) >= buf_size) {
        if (buf_size >= PATH_MAX) {
            free(buffer);
            return NULL;
        }

        buf_size = buf_size <= PATH_MAX / 2 ? buf_size * 2 : PATH_MAX;
        buffer = xrealloc(buffer, buf_size);
    }

    buffer[read] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}

static int
read_file_info(const char *dir_path, const char *file_name, struct file_info *file_info) {
    char *full_path = xmalloc(strlen(dir_path) + strlen(file_name) + 2);
    concat_path(dir_path, file_name, full_path);

    struct stat st;
    if (lstat(full_path, &st) == -1) {
        file_error("failed to get information", full_path);
        free(full_path);
        return MINOR_ERROR;
    }

    file_info->st = st;
    file_info->type = get_file_type(st.st_mode);

    file_info->target = NULL;
    if (file_info->type == SYMLINK) {
        file_info->target = read_link(full_path, st.st_size);
    }

    const char *real_name = (file_name[0] == '\0') ? dir_path : file_name;
    file_info->name = strdup(real_name);

    if (file_info->type == DIRECTORY) {
        file_info->path = full_path;
    } else {
        free(full_path);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static void
free_file_info(struct file_info *file_info, const int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        free(file_info[i].name);
        if (file_info[i].target != NULL) {
            free(file_info[i].target);
        }
        if (file_info[i].type == DIRECTORY) {
            free(file_info[i].path);
        }
    }
}

static void
list_dir(const char *path) { // NOLINT(*-no-recursion): recursion is required
    static int first_call = 1;
    int buf_size = BUF_SIZE;
    const struct dirent *entry;

    DIR *dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir == NULL) {
        file_error("failed to open directory", path);
        return;
    }

    int owner_w = 0;
    int size_w = 0;
    int entry_no = 0;

    struct file_info *files = xmalloc(buf_size * sizeof(struct file_info));

    while ((entry = readdir(dir))) {
        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        struct file_info info;
        if (read_file_info(path, entry->d_name, &info) != 0) {
            continue;
        }

        files[entry_no] = info;

        int owner_len = (int) strlen(get_owner(info.st.st_uid));
        int size_len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%ld", info.st.st_size);
        owner_w = (owner_len > owner_w) ? owner_len : owner_w;
        size_w = (size_len > size_w) ? size_len : size_w;

        if (entry_no++ == buf_size - 1) {
            buf_size *= 2;
            struct file_info *new_files = xrealloc(files, buf_size * sizeof(struct file_info));
            files = new_files;
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
    qsort(files, entry_no, sizeof(struct file_info), compare_file_name);

    if (!first_call) {
        printf("\n");
    }
    first_call = 0;

    printf("%s:\n", path);
    for (int i = 0; i < entry_no; i++) {
        print_file_info(&files[i], owner_w, size_w);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < entry_no; i++) {
        if (files[i].type == DIRECTORY) {
            list_dir(files[i].path);
        }
    }

    free_file_info(files, entry_no);
    free(files);
}

static int
myrls(const char *path) {
    init();

    struct stat st;
    if (lstat(path, &st) == -1) {
        file_error("cannot access", path);
        return MINOR_ERROR;
    }

    if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) {
        list_dir(path);
    } else { /* if myrls is called against a file, pay the price of double call to lstat()
        in favor of code simplicity - it would not be executed recursively anyway */
        struct file_info info;
        if ((read_file_info(path, "", &info)) != 0) {
            return MINOR_ERROR;
        }
        print_file_info(&info, 0, 0);
        free_file_info(&info, 1);
    }

    return exit_status;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 2) {
        error(FATAL_ERROR, 0, "too many arguments");
    }

    const char *path = (argc == 2) ? argv[1] : "./";
    return myrls(path);
}
```

Comment: Note that tree walking is a classic example of something that can often be coded iteratively, maintaining your own stack/queue rather than using the program stack. Efficiency may be significantly better, with the right data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reduce allocations and long string copies**

Rather than `stpcpy(full_path, dir_name);`, which gets longer and longer on recursion, allocate once a max path length buffer and pass in it the current directory and its length.  Then no copying of the `dir_name` is needed and copying the file name only needs to copy from the end as that buffer is re-used.

In my experience, this approach *significantly* increases performance.

```
// Return non-zero on error.
// len: current used length.
// sz: max size of buffer.
// path: buffer to form the path.
// f(): some function to perform on state and path.
// state: Some context for f().
int DirFunc(size_t len, size_t sz, char path[sz],
    int (f)(void *state, const char *filepathname), void *state) {
  int retval = 0;
  DIR *dir;
  if ((dir = opendir(path)) != NULL) {
    struct dirent *in_file;
    while ((in_file = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
      // Appned file name.
      int le = snprintf(&path[len], sz - len, "%s", in_file->d_name);
      // Look for excessively long paths.
      if (le < 0 || (unsigned) le >= sz - len) {
        return -1;
      }
      retval = f(state, path);  // Do something with path.
      if (retval) {
        return retval;
      }
      if (in_file->d_type & DT_DIR) {
        if (path[len] != '.'
            || (strcmp(&path[len], ".") && strcmp(&path[len], ".."))) {
          strcpy(&path[len + le], "/");
          retval = DirFunc(len + le + 1, sz, path, f, state);
          path[len] = '\0';  // Lop off appended filename.
          if (retval) {
            return retval;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    retval = closedir(dir);
    if (retval) {
      return retval;
    }
  }
  return retval;
}
```

**Use matching specifier**

`snprintf(NULL, 0, "%ld", info.st.st_size);` *assumes* `info.st.st_size` is a `long`.  It is type [`off_t`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html#tag_13_67) which may be like `long` or wider or narrower.  Instead cast this *signed* type to widest signed type and then print.

```
// snprintf(NULL, 0, "%ld", info.st.st_size);
snprintf(NULL, 0, "%jd", (intmax_t) info.st.st_size);
```

Likewise with `uid`

```
... *get_owner(uid_t uid) {
// sprintf(user_info->name, "%u", uid);
sprintf(user_info->name, "%ju", (uintmax_t) uid);
```

**Avoid overflow**

Since `strcpy(user_info->name, pwd->pw_name)` may overflow the destination buffer, perhaps create a `int xstrcpy(size_t n, char dest[n], const char *s)`.  Perhaps a copy that never overflows and returns a success flag.

```
int xstrcpy(size_t n, char dest[n], const char *s) {
  if (strlen(s) >= n) {
    if (n > 0) {
      dest[0] = '\0';
    }
    return -1; //failure
  }
  strcpy(dest, s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the review. For me personally, it looks the most useful of all the above - definitely accepting. Special thanks for the code examples, it makes it much easier to understand what you mean. I will later try to add the results of profiling after optimizations so that it will be a clear example for others

Answer (score 6):

## Use `nftw()`

Since you are already using POSIX functions like `lstat()`, consider using [`nftw()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3p.html) to get all directory entries. It can even recurse for you, but if you want your output to be sorted, that might be an issue. However, even without recursing it is quite useful, as it will `stat()` entries for you as well.

## The user info cache is not efficient

Your user info cache is just a linked list. Lookups will thus be \$O(N)\$, which means that if you have many different uids on your system, your cache becomes very slow. There are various ways you could make this faster, like by using a balanced binary tree, a trie or a hash table.

Alternatively, just limit the size of your linked list to no more than a handful of entries. Whenever you have a cache hit, move the entry in the cache to the front of the list, as it is likely you will see the same uid multiple times in a row. If you have a cache miss, and you have already reached the size limit, remove the last element (which will be the one least recently used) and add the new element to the front.

## Possible buffer overflow

There is a possible buffer overflow in this line:

```
strcpy(user_info->name, pwd->pw_name);
```

Note that usernames can be larger than 32 characters. Regardless, it is always better to use `strncpy()` when the destination buffer has a fixed size (and be mindful of how it handles the last byte). You could also consider using `strdup()` to copy strings.

Comment: Thanks for your review. By the way, how efficient can ntfw() be compared to what I used in the first place? Does it perform the same and it's just about convenience, or there's actually some differences?

Comment: I think it is more convenient. It *might* be faster because it's only one function call to scan a whole directory (or even recursively scan directories), so it could use more efficient system calls. However, only benchmarking can tell.

Answer (score 5):

This restriction seems unnecessary:

```
    if (argc > 2) {
        error(FATAL_ERROR, 0, "too many arguments");
    }
```

Just loop over `argv` and handle all the arguments, as similar commands do.  That's what users expect.  Special-case the no-arguments invocation:

```
    if (argc < 2) {
        return myrls(".");
    } else {
        while (*++argv) {
            int result = myrls(*argv);
            if (result) { return result; }
        }
    }
```

Or even point `argv` at the default argument list:

```
    if (argc < 2) {
        argv = { NULL, (char*)".", NULL };
    }
    while (*++argv) {
        int result = myrls(*argv);
        if (result) { return result; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Actually, it was a temporary solution as I later added some options using [getopt(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) and proper argument handling. I apologize for forgetting to mention this.